# MVVM - How to bind Visibility of a HierarchicalDataTemplate item to a ViewModel field

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a HierarchicalDataTemplate that holds a number of items and has a small image next to each item. It is the visibility of these images I want to bind. Whether an item's image should be visible is dependent on whether the item appears in a DataTable on a server.

In order to determine an item's visibility, I need both the ID number of that item and the interface that accesses the server. The interface is kept as a field in the ViewModel.

Ideally I'd just have this method in my ViewModel, if I could bind based on the item's ID:

```
public Visibility ItemIsInTable(int ID)
{
    string sql = "SELECT ID FROM MyTable WHERE ID = " + ID;
    DataTable dataTable = serverInterface.FetchDataFromDatabase(sql);

    if (dataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
        return Visibility.Visible;
    else
        return Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

How can my binding rely on both the item ID and my ViewModel Interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ViewModel Property should be boolean, and you will use a converter.

```
public bool ItemIsInTable {get { ... } set { ...; OnPropertyChanged("ItemIsInTable"); }}
```

[Edit]

Ok.
You must have a `ObservableColletction` of Items (in my example `ItemsSource`)

```
class ItemSource: INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    public int Id {get { ... } set { ...; OnPropertyChanged("Id"); }}
    public bool ItemIsInTable {get { ... } set { ...; OnPropertyChanged("ItemIsInTable"); }}
    ....
}
```

In your ViewModel:

```
ObservableColletction<ItemSource> ItemsSource  {get { ... } set { ...; OnPropertyChanged("ItemsSource"); }}
```

Now you should verify the Id

```
foreach(var item in ItemsSource)
    item.ItemIsInTable = MethodToVerifyIdInDataBase(item.Id);
```

[/Edit]

XAML like this:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding ItemSource}"   >
    <Grid Visibility="{Binding ItemIsInTable, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" >
        ....
    </Grid>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

App.Xaml:

```
<converters:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter"/>
```

Converter class:

```
public class BoolToVisibilityConverter: IValueConverter 
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var rv = Visibility.Visible;
        try
        {
            if (value != null)
                rv = (bool)value ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        catch
        {
            // ignored
        }
        return rv;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (value != null) && (value == (object)Visibility.Visible);
    }
}
```

Comment: Truth be told I had removed my bool-to-visibility converter to try and make things easier... guess that didn't work. I'll try this next.

Comment: OK! The real piece I was missing was adding the boolean 'ItemIsInTable' to my 'ItemSource' class and populating it from the ViewModel, there really isn't any way to have that information in my item unless I put it there.